# How to detect dog feces?

Tags: analytical-chemistry

I am working on building a robot to detect and pickup dog poop.  I have looked at the concentrations of the various components and simple chemical/electrical ways to detect them.  The best component to detect seems to be methanethiol but I could not find a simple sensor to detect it.  I found this sensor http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-shipping-4CH3SH-10-sensor-methanethiol-sensor-electrochemical-gas-sensor/32381228085.html and I was wondering if it could work for this purpose, I could not find much information on the sensor.  I was also thinking something like an alcohol sensor could work.